# Do <li> inherits event handlers by default from <ul>?

Tags: javascript, html

Do my li tags can inherits event handlers from ul 'by accident' ?
Sometimes "item1" sticks with "item2" and I get 2in1:

```
    <ul id="todo"  ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
        <li id="item1" draggable="true"  ondragstart="drag(event)">Task 1</li>
        <li id="item2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Task 2</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="inprogress" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>


    <ul id="done" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: no, they don't inherit the event-handler, but your `li`'s are a part of the `ul` (kind of) and if your mouse is over the `li`, it is also over the surrounding `ul`. And therefore the events are triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "by accident", it's called [event bubbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_bubbling). Imagine you have a bunch of stacked components, a `<li>` contained in a `<ul>` contained in a `<div>`. If you click on on the innermost element, the `<li>` in this example, you also clicked on the `<ul>` given that it contains the `<li>`. Same happens for all events.

What you can do, in your `allowDrop()` function, is to check for the event's [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) element and see if that's an `<ul>` or a `<li>` using the [Element.tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) property.

```
function allowDrop (event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'li') {
    return // the event was bubbled up
  }

  // your normal code goes here
}
```

Disclaimer: untested code but **should** work :)

Comment: Thanks very much !

Comment: Yes, but I've applied it to my drop(e) function :)